# app runs within Xcode project, but not after built

Tags: xcode8, archive, hung

I have a Xcode project, my small mac app runs all successfully within Xcode test run after compile, but by running the debug or release build by itself, the app become unresponsive after start running.  No error or warning during building.
I don't know where to look to start troubleshooting this, so totally stuck.  How do you start investigating for the issue like this?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by setting an exception breakpoint for your project in Xcode. Xcode will pause your app when it throws an exception. Exceptions are thrown when runtime errors occur in your code. Setting an exception breakpoint can help you find the problem in your code.

If no exception breakpoints fire when you debug the app in Xcode, you will need to update your question with more information about your app. Is your app a GUI app or a command-line app? Does your app do anything special at startup, such as load files?